# Typescript: how to import a class from a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I would like to :

- Import a js file that defines a class: `./myClass/index.js`
- Declare the public methods of `MyClass` somewhere (in index.ts or a specified declaration file, I really don't know how to do it)
- Have a typescript file that exposes the class: `index.ts`

something like

```
// index.ts
import MyClass from './myClass' // or require, or anything that would work
export {MyClass}
```

and

```
// myClass/index.js
export default class MyClass {
  ...
}
```

This obviously does not work, as the import of `./myClass/index` won't find the module.

The thing is, I tried to create a `./myClass/index.d.ts` file based on [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-class-d-ts.html), but no matter what, I still have  a **Error: Cannot find module './myClass/index.js'** error at runtime :(

I feel like I miss some typescript basics here but I'm striving to find some clear resources.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no `export default class` in JavaScript. What you can do is write your JS file like this. `myClass/index.js`

```
"use strict";
class MyClass {
  hello(name) {
    console.log(`Hello ${name}`);
  }

}
exports.default = MyClass;
```

Create a Type definitions for it. `myClass/index.d.ts`

```
export default class MyClass {
  hello(name: string): void;
}
```

You can then import it into your TypeScript like this.

```
/// <reference path="./myClass/index.d.ts" />
import MyClass from "./myClass";

const my = new MyClass();
my.hello("Stack Overflow");
```

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple 0_o. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @goenning why do you say there is not export default class ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_the_default_export . I think that statement may confuse people

Answer (score 6):

at the end of the your javascript file ,
write this

```
exports.MyClass = MyClass;
```

in ts files

```
import * as  IzendaSynergy  from './izenda/izenda_ui.js';
```

or

```
import { IzendaSynergy } from './izenda/izenda_ui.js';
```

in tsconfig.json file

```
  "allowJs": true
```

Comment: `allowJs` was key for me. Thanks!

Comment: Me I don't use exports.MyClass = MyClass but export default class MyClass with the "allowJs": true