# Use JavaScript class in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a problem introducing TypeScript to our JavaScript project.
First I want to use TypeScript only in my part of the code, leaving the JavaScript untouched.

Now I try to use a JavaScript class in my TypeScript code, but I don't find a solution in the last days.

The head of my TypeScript class with import of the JavaScript:

```
import { BaseLogic } from "../baseLogic";
export class ClaimLogic extends BaseLogic {
...
```

The JavaScript class ("baseLogic.js"):

```
module.exports = class BaseLogic {
    constructor(meta, logger) {
    ...
```

My *.d.ts file ("baseLogic.d.ts"):

```
export class BaseLogic {
    meta: any;
    log: any;

    constructor(meta: any, logger: any)
}
```

The head of the compiled JavaScript:

```
const baseLogic_1 = require("../baseLogic");
class ClaimLogic extends baseLogic_1.BaseLogic {
...
```

As you see in the compiled JavaScript *baseLogic_1.BaseLogic* is used.
This results in following error:

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

With only *baseLogic_1* after the *extends* keyword in the JavaScript file all is fine.

I have no idea about a solution and hope you can help me!

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40463441/typescript-how-to-import-a-class-from-a-javascript-file

Answer (score 3):

Your import suppose to be `import * as BaseLogic from "../baseLogic";`.

In that way you will get the Class that you put on `module.exports`.

Comment: With this import I musst use "extends BaseLogic.BaseLogic" in the TypeScript code. If not, I got the error "is not a constructor or function type"

Comment: No, you will get the Class, so you should `extend BaseLogic`

Comment: Sadly the TypeScript compiler is of another opinion

Answer (score 1):

The codesnipet in `baseLogic.js` exports the **class**.

```
module.exports = class BaseLogic {
  constructor(meta, logger) {
  ...
}
```

You try to access with `class ClaimLogic extends baseLogic_1.BaseLogic` an object that includes the class `BaseLogic`

### Solution

```
import BaseLogic from '../baseLogic'
// or:  const BaseLogic = require("../baseLogic");

class ClaimLogic extends BaseLogic {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but with your solution I got following error: "../baseLogic has no default export"

Comment: can you try it again with `import {BaseLogic} from '../baseLogic'`

Comment: Now the error in the TypeScript file is gone, but it's lead to the same compiled JS file.

Comment: I think there is a problem with the *.d.ts file, but I don't now

Comment: do you try to import the java- oder typescript file?

Comment: I want to use the class, exported in the js file, in my ts file.

Comment: and what is `baseLogic.d.ts` doing in this scenario?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152236/discussion-between-juliang-and-roman).