# How to import a javascript class into typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am making a game in which I have a js class that I am exporting as follows:

```
var Game = cc.Class({
    name: "WS",
});
module.exports = Game;
```

The above is in a file `ws.js`.

In the same directory as `ws.js`, I have a TypeScript file called `transitions.ts` where I try to import the `Game` module as follows:

```
import Game = require ("./Game");
```

I am getting an error: `cannot find module './Game'`

Comment: Do you use webpack?

Comment: This isn't a JavaScript/TypeScript thing, it's to do with what you're using to handle `require` calls -- Webpack, RollupJS, Node.js...

Comment: Uh, use `require("./ws.js")` if that's what the file is called, not `Game.js`?

Comment: *"Also, I would like to know..."* Ask **one** question per question, not two or three. I was doing some cleanup on the question, so I removed that bit.

Comment: That `import Game = require ("./Game");` looks weird, but [it's valid in TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: how to import a class from a javascript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40463441/typescript-how-to-import-a-class-from-a-javascript-file)

Comment: Also, probably [Migrating from JavaScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html), and [Getting Declaration Files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html#getting-declaration-files) in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Exporting your class as a module will allow you to import it as one in another file.

```
Class House { blah.. blah };
export default House;

import House from '../filename';
```

Answer (score 1):

## Import the JS module as `any`

Just replace `import` with `const`:

```
const Game = require("./Game");
```

## Or, write a module definition first

The other solution is to describe the JavaScript module in a `.d.ts` file:

```
// Game.d.ts
declare class Game {
  // …
}
export = Game;
```

Then, you can import the JS module:

```
import Game = require("./Game");
```